# Are there any plugins to open SAP Visual Enterprise Author files (.rh) in blender?

Tags: compatibility

The company I work for has a script for 3DS Max that can read and write .rh files for an easy transition back and forth between Max and SAP Visual Enterprise Author. Has anyone heard of any plugins for blender to do the same?

Here is the plugin [.dlf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TXW3qG-nlaixZ7f0_xvd-NnlBrCs0RvZ/view?usp=sharing). I was unable to open it but I don't currently have an editor other than Blender.
Here is an example [.rh file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaM8q_xZctY_bQXD34QBsBm_Je1wxiVI/view?usp=sharing) that SAP Visual Enterprise Author creates and saves as.

Comment: Not sure. However, if no add-on is available and you have some basic programming knowledge, it should be straight forward to code it based on the templates that come with blender *(text editor > python templates > import...)* - much easier than writing maxscript. I suggest add the file specifications or any example rh file to your question so we can have a look...

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I managed to track down the file that I believe 3DS Max uses and I apologize as I am out of my element with this stuff. It's a .dlf file that was provided by SAP off their website circa 2015. I have opened it in blender and I don't think it's able to interpret it.

Comment: Question Is: Is the format human readable like [obj](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_OBJ) or a binary? Are there any file specifications? Can you open it up in an editor? Can you provide a file?

Comment: SAP can export out as an obj or fbx but you end up losing spatial information etc with that format. I have attached files in the original comment. Hopefully, that is helpful to get me on the right path.